# How to set names of classes?

Tags: java, generics

My code is:

```
public static <K, V> void initMapperJob( Job job,
        Collection<WebPage.Field> fields,  Class<K> outKeyClass, Class<V>
        outValueClass,   Class<? extends GoraMapper<String, WebPage, K, V>> mapperClass,     
        Class<? extends Partitioner<K, V>> partitionerClass, boolean reuseObjects)   
        throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
               DataStore<String, WebPage> store = createWebStore(job.getConfiguration(), String.class,    WebPage.class );
            ........ 
    }
```

I change as like follows:

```
        public static <K, V, P extends PersistentBase, F extends Fields> void initMapperJob(Job job,
          Collection<F> fields,
          Class<K> outKeyClass, Class<V> outValueClass,
          Class<? extends GoraMapper<String, P, K, V>> mapperClass,
          Class<? extends Partitioner<K, V>> partitionerClass, boolean reuseObjects)
      throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        DataStore<String, P> store = createWebStore(job.getConfiguration(),
            String.class, P.class );

....
      }
```

My question is: how to set class of generics via java for the following line?

> DataStore store = createWebStore(job.getConfiguration(),
>                   String.class, **P.class** );

If I set  as like ( P.class or P) , an error has occurred .

The following method is called.

```
public static <K, V extends Persistent> DataStore<K, V> createWebStore(Configuration conf,
      Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> persistentClass){...}
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: That is not possible, because of type erasure.  You need to accept the `Class<P>` as a parameter.

Comment: You cannot refer to the `class` of P.  You can only use `class` on literal class names.

Comment: (P is not really a class, it's just a token used for pattern matching.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a parameter of type `Class<P>` and use it (instead of P.class). you will then need to go to the site(s) where `initMapperJob()` and add that extra parameter to the call.

```
    public static <K, V, P extends PersistentBase, F extends Fields> 
    void initMapperJob(Job job,
      Collection<F> fields,
      Class<K> outKeyClass, Class<V> outValueClass,
      Class<? extends GoraMapper<String, P, K, V>> mapperClass,
      Class<? extends Partitioner<K, V>> partitionerClass, 
      boolean reuseObjects,
      Class<P> pClass) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    DataStore<String, P> store = createWebStore(job.getConfiguration(),
        String.class, pClass);

    ....
  }
```